# Ajax traz resultado apenas no console?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Boa tarde pessoal, consigo trazer um resultado no log, mas na div não é repassada, segue meu fonte:

Index.php

```js
var teste;
$.ajax({
    url: 'conversa.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        $("#conversa").html(res);
        teste = $("#conversa").html(res);
        console.log(document.getElementById("conversa"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

conversa.php

```html
<?php
include '../../abreConexao.php';
session_start();

$query = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE meu_id='" . $_SESSION['id-cadastro'] . "' AND parceiro_id='" . $_SESSION['paquera_chat'] . "' OR meu_id='" . $_SESSION['paquera_chat'] . "' AND parceiro_id='" . $_SESSION['id-cadastro'] . "' ORDER BY data_hora ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $variavel .= '{"_id":"' . $fetch['parceiro_id'] . '","text":"' . $fetch['mensagem'] . '","userId":"' . $fetch['meu_id'] . '","date":"' . $fetch['data_hora'] . '"},';
}
echo $variavel;  
?>
```

[image: Console]

Só queria mesmo pegar o select da conversa.php e exibir na index via ajax.
Fico no aguardo pessoal, obrigado.

--Resolvido

```js
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'conversa.php', 
  type: 'POST', 
  success: function(res){ 
    $("#conversa").empty();
    $("#conversa").append(res);
    teste = document.getElementById('conversa').innerHTML; 
    console.log(document.getElementById("conversa"));
  }
   });
```

Comment: O que exatamente vocês quer exibir dentro da div? A resposta está vindo um objeto com várias informações!

Comment: quero exibir tudo mesmo.

Comment: Então, mas pra você fazer isso, acho que você vai ter que fazer um loop para adicionar cada elemento na div

Comment: exatamente como está no console

Comment: porque olha o echo na minha pagina php fica assim:{"_id":"57","text":"oi mae","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T13:45:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Oi filho","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:47:00.000Z"},

Comment: Tenta fazer o seguinte:  $("#conversa").html(JSON.stringify(res)); pra ver se aparece o objeto inteiro dentro da div

Comment: Tenta usar .append(res) ao invés de .html(res)

Comment: entao usei o append, mas quando dou alert da object object

Comment: $("#conversa").html(JSON.stringify(res)) tambem nao apareceu nada

Comment: fiz mais um teste aqui galera
$("#conversa").append(res); funcionou
Muitoooo obrigado.

Comment: Coloque o resultado como resposta e, depois de dois dias, marque-a como resposta certa.