# Erro ao exibir variavel no vetor

Tags: javascript

Boa noite pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda com um vetor em JS...

Quando insiro desta maneira o mesmo funciona ok, exibe todas as mensagens, mas quando coloco a variável teste no lugar ele não exibe nada:

```js
var teste = document.getElementById('conversa').innerHTML; 
return {
  "messages":[
   {"_id":"57","text":"oi mae","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T13:45:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Oi filho","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:47:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Leo","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:51:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"...","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:52:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Ha","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:52:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"XD","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:56:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"...","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:56:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Ahh","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:57:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"T","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:58:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"F","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:59:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"X","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:02:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Kk","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:03:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Xp","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:06:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"...","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:08:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"ok","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T14:08:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Jdjjd","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:09:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"K","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:14:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"leo","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T14:14:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"ke","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T14:16:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"L","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:16:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"leo","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-20T16:40:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"leo","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-20T16:41:00.000Z"},
  ]
   };
```

Poderiam me ajudar com uma solução, preciso que os dados sejam dinâmicos dentro do vetor "messages"... e essa variável teste é dinâmica porem ao inserir lá dentro não exibe nada na página.

Obs.: Todo esse conteúdo

```
{"_id":"57","text":"oi mae","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T13:45:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Oi filho","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:47:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Leo","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:51:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"...","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:52:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Ha","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:52:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"XD","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:56:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"...","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:56:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Ahh","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:57:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"T","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:58:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"F","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T13:59:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"X","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:02:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Kk","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:03:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Xp","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:06:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"...","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:08:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"ok","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T14:08:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"Jdjjd","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:09:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"K","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:14:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"leo","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T14:14:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"ke","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-19T14:16:00.000Z"},{"_id":"54","text":"L","userId":"57","date":"2016-10-19T14:16:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"leo","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-20T16:40:00.000Z"},{"_id":"57","text":"leo","userId":"54","date":"2016-10-20T16:41:00.000Z"},
```

Está dentro da variável `teste`.

Comment: `return JSON.parse(teste)`;

Comment: no console deu esse erro ao colocar o codigo acima: Syntax Error: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: Ah agora eu entendi octaciojb, eu abri esse tópico para pegar o conteúdo da div, fluiu legal ja foi resolvido... porém agora o problema é diferente conforme descrito acima.

Comment: Ok,desmarcada. Boa sorte na solução.

Comment: Me ajudem aí pessoal =(

Comment: Ainda está constando como pergunta duplicada mas não é

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ajax traz resultado apenas no console?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160232/ajax-traz-resultado-apenas-no-console)